# Catalyst: UIReferenceLibraryViewController missing in UIKit?

Tags: xcode, uikit, mac-catalyst

In my iOS app I use UIReferenceLibraryViewController (UIKit) to lookup words in the dictionary. Works fine. When building for Catalyst I get:

```
Showing Recent Issues
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIReferenceLibraryViewController

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIReferenceLibraryViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WoordvinderViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AnagramViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is UIReferenceLibraryViewController just missing from the UIKit framework, or am I missing something?

Apple's code level support tells me to report a bug... eh.. feedback in the bug reporter, but the bug report goes unacknowledged. Xcode 12 beta did not fix it, nor did Xcode 12 release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class is not implemented for Catalyst yet despite the docs saying it's supported. I even checked the macOS port of UIKit at `/System/iOSSupport/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/Versions/A/UIKitCore` and found no reference to the class.

I guess the only solution, for now, is to create a macOS plugin that shows the native lookup popover by calling [`NSView.showDefinition()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483747-showdefinition).

Comment: Thanks! I may just omit the definition lookup in the Mac version until Apple finds the precious time to fix this. It’s just a little extra, and not core to my App.

Comment: Ugh. I filed this as a documentation bug. FB9980346